# Override a spring bean which already has an alias

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a spring bean declared on a code I can't change or have control over, it's declared like this:

```xml
    <alias name="defaultRemoveSheetsDecorator" alias="removeSheetsDecorator"/>
    <bean id="defaultRemoveSheetsDecorator"
          class="com.hybris.backoffice.excel.exporting.RemoveSheetsDecorator">
        <property name="sheetsToRemove">
            <list>
                <value type="com.hybris.backoffice.excel.template.ExcelTemplateConstants$UtilitySheet">
                    PK
                </value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And Im trying to override it like this:

```xml
    <alias name="myRemoveSheetsDecorator" alias="removeSheetsDecorator" />
    <bean id="myRemoveSheetsDecorator"
          class="com.mypackage.MyRemoveSheetDecorator" parent="defaultRemoveSheetsDecorator">
        <property name="sheetsToRemove">
            <list>
                <value type="com.hybris.backoffice.excel.template.ExcelTemplateConstants$UtilitySheet">
                    PK
                </value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

But for some reason when I get the bean `removeSheetsDecorator` and check it's class with `getClass()`, It is still pointing to the original bean ??

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? The way I read it first, you have a bean with a specified name, but you want to be able to refer to that one bean with an alias (perhaps for autowiring qualifiers). By your final statement, it looks like you want a copy of the bean (with a new name).

Comment: There is a bean defined OOTB `removeSheetsDecorator` and used in multiple place, I am trying to extends/override with my custom bean

Comment: are you doing the override in the correct context? core context vs webcontext. As I see it, this bean needs to be declared in <customBackofficename>-backoffice-spring.xml
Make sure you are not changing it in the spring-web.xml

Answer (score 0):

looks like parent causing issue .

```
  <alias name="myRemoveSheetsDecorator" alias="removeSheetsDecorator" />
<bean id="myRemoveSheetsDecorator"
      class="com.mypackage.MyRemoveSheetDecorator" >
    <property name="sheetsToRemove">
        <list>
            <value type="com.hybris.backoffice.excel.template.ExcelTemplateConstants$UtilitySheet">
                PK
            </value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: can you explain why it's causing an issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, hybris is full of features. Namely, *ext-backoffice* has a specific approach in bean overriding. Basically, you have two options:

[Bean Extenders](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/94ac56a0aa9f486490bbe1251d994457.html?version=2011) mechanism
E.g. your Sample *-spring.xml would look like:

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:cng="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/spring"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
           http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/spring 
           http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/spring/cng-spring.xsd">

        <cng:list-extender bean="defaultExcelExportDecorators" unique="true">
           <cng:add>
              <ref bean="myRemoveSheetsDecorator" />
              <bean class="com.mypackage.MyRemoveSheetDecorator" />
           </cng:add>
           <cng:remove>
              <ref bean="removeSheetsDecorator"/>
           </cng:remove>
        </cng:list-extender>
    </beans>
```

[Customize](http://www.daharveyjr.com/hybris-how-to-override-a-bean-in-backoffice-web-spring-xml/) mechanism. In this case do not forget to reset OOTB configuration after login to Backoffice (Press F4 - Reset everyrhing - Wait - Press F4).